# jquery ui buttonset to select a checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to update a hidden field based on user selected button

Code:

```
<div id="bankRadioButtons">
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank1" name="bankRadioButtons" /><label for="Bank1">Bank1</label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank2" name="bankRadioButtons" /><label for="Bank2">Bank2</label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank3" name="bankRadioButtons" /><label for="Bank3">Bank3</label></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedBank" value="" />
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#bankRadioButtons").buttonset();
$("#bankRadioButtons").buttonset().bind('click', function(event) {
  // I need to write code here to update the hidden field 'selectedBank' based on user selected bank radio button

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

Give your radio buttons a `value` then you can use jQuery's `change()` and `val()` methods.

> **jQuery.change()** Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.
>
> **jQuery.val()** Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gxksB/)

#### Sample

```
<div id="bankRadioButtons">
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank1" value="Bank1" name="bankRadioButtons" /><label for="Bank1">Bank1</label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank2" value="Bank2" name="bankRadioButtons" /><label for="Bank2">Bank2</label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank3" value="Bank3" name="bankRadioButtons" /><label for="Bank3">Bank3</label></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedBank" value="" />

$("input[type='radio'][name='bankRadioButtons']").change(function(event) {
    $("input[type='hidden'][name='selectedBank']").val($(this).val());
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [jQuery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

### Update

The following would will in better performance. Use `class` and the `id` attribute in html.

```
<div id="bankRadioButtons">
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank1" value="Bank1" name="bankRadioButtons" class="bankRadioButtons" /><label for="Bank1">Bank1</label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank2" value="Bank2" name="bankRadioButtons" class="bankRadioButtons"/><label for="Bank2">Bank2</label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" id="Bank3" value="Bank3" name="bankRadioButtons" class="bankRadioButtons"/><label for="Bank3">Bank3</label></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedBank" id="selectedBank" value="" />

$(".bankRadioButtons").change(function(event) {
    $("#selectedBank").val($(this).val());
});
```

### Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxksB/1/)

Comment: Thanks. If i use .val() its returning me "on" so i used $(this).attr("id")

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$("#bankRadioButtons").buttonset();
$("#bankRadioButtons").buttonset().bind('click', function(event) {
 switch(this.id)
    {
      case "Bank1" : $("#selectedBank").val("Bank1"); 
       break;  // and then case "Bank2" etc.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var value = $("input[@name=bankRadioButtons]:checked").val();
$("input[@name=selectedBank]").val(value);
```

Good-Luck !